# ERC-20 without events

Tags: erc-20, events

I have created a non-compliant ERC-20 token that does not emit any events. I do not want to fix this bug, because fixing it produces other troubles.

So, an ERC-20 token with this bug (not emitting events) will work in practice or not?

I realized Etherscan won't notify of deposits. Maybe MetaMask won't update dynamically (will it?)

What are other possible troubles? Are they significant?

Well, I'll disclose why I did so: I made a ERC-20 wrapper around a ERC-1155 token. There is no way to detect transfers of this ERC-1155 without special support in the ERC-1155 contract. We anyway should switch to ERC-1155 in the future. So I do ERC-20 as a hack.

Comment: You will no record of transfers.

Comment: @goodvibration I've just invented a solution: I will instead lock ERC-1155 funds in a ERC-20 contract. So it can be made compliant.

Answer (score 0):

In theory your contract is ERC20 compatible because there is no way to enforce (or even check) whether a contract emits the required events every time. And in any case there is no standard method for finding out whether a contract is ERC20 compatible or not.

Anyway, this is mostly a matter of how different third parties have implemented their ERC20 integrations. The core ERC20 functionality will work but various third parties will probably have problems displaying the results.

Comment: I already stated all this in the question. The answer is to list the _particular_ problems and estimate whether the troubles are big.

Comment: Very well, in my opinion I gave new information but you don't have to agree.

Comment: And most 3rd parties actually rely on `Transfer` events being available to them.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a EIP-20 compliant token. Some services that relies on events will not work, like block explorer or light wallets.

From [EIP-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) specification:

> transfer
>
> Transfers `_value` amount of tokens to address `_to`, and **MUST** fire the `Transfer` event. [..]